# rename and send all child nodes based on value of element in child node in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

My input is:

```
    <Recordset>
      <Report_ID>
        <Record>
          <Report_ID>A1</Report_ID>
          <name1>a1</name1>
          <name2>a1</name2>
          <name3>a1</name3>
          <name4>true</name4>
        </Record>
        <Record>
          <Report_ID>A1</Report_ID>
          <name1>a1</name1>
          <name2>b1</name2>
          <name3>t1</name3>
          <name4>false</name4>
        </Record>
        <Record>
          <Report_ID>A1</Report_ID>
          <name1>a1</name1>
          <name2>a1</name2>
          <name3>a1</name3>
          <name4>false</name4>
        </Record>
   </Report_ID>
   <Report_ID>
      <Record>
        <Report_ID>B1</Report_ID>
        <name1>a1</name1>
        <name2>a1</name2>
        <name3>a1</name3>
        <name4>true</name4>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Report_ID>B1</Report_ID>
        <name1>a1</name1>
        <name2>a1</name2>
        <name3>a1</name3>
        <name4>true</name4>
    </Record>
  </Report_ID>
</Recordset>
```

Initially I had multiple records under one Report_Id, which I've grouped by Unique Report_Id. Next I want to achieve the below:

Target: If in one Report_ID any of name4 is "false" all the Records under that Report_Id should go and the parent node should be renamed as Report_ID_Complicated, if all the name4 values are true then it should be renamed as Report_ID_Simple. The grouping is fine...There has to be another check condition and the Parent nodes accordingly renamed.

```
<Recordset>
      <Report_ID_Complicated>
        <Record>
          <Report_ID>A1</Report_ID>
          <name1>a1</name1>
          <name2>a1</name2>
          <name3>a1</name3>
          <name4>true</name4>
        </Record>
        <Record>
          <Report_ID>A1</Report_ID>
          <name1>a1</name1>
          <name2>b1</name2>
          <name3>t1</name3>
          <name4>false</name4>
        </Record>
        <Record>
          <Report_ID>A1</Report_ID>
          <name1>a1</name1>
          <name2>a1</name2>
          <name3>a1</name3>
          <name4>false</name4>
        </Record>
   </Report_ID_Complicated>
   <Report_ID_Simple>
      <Record>
        <Report_ID>B1</Report_ID>
        <name1>a1</name1>
        <name2>a1</name2>
        <name3>a1</name3>
        <name4>true</name4>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Report_ID>B1</Report_ID>
        <name1>a1</name1>
        <name2>a1</name2>
        <name3>a1</name3>
        <name4>true</name4>
    </Record>
  </Report_ID_Simple>
</Recordset>
```

**UPDATE:**

Tim's answer's works perfectly, but I had written the bellow code to group the Report Ids now when i try to merge Tim's answer with my previous code am getting "an xstl for-each element must not contain an xsl:template element"

i believe that we can't apply template inside for-each, so it would be of great help if you could point me in the right direction as to how i can merge both the codes.

My Xslt Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="kReport_Id" match="Record" use="Report_Id"/>
<xsl:key name="kname4" match="Record" use="concat(Report_Id,name4)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns:File_Intermediate>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns:File/RecordSet/Record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kReport_Id',Report_Id))]">
            <Report_Id>
                <ReportID_Simple>
                    <xsl:variable name="vReport_Id" select="Report_Id"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../Record[Report_Id = $vReport_Id][generate-id() = generate-id(key('kname4',concat(Report_Id,name4)))]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="../Record[Report_Id = $vReport_Id][name4=current()/name4]">
                            <xsl:variable name="name4" select="name4"/>
                            <xsl:if test="name4='true'">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ReportID_Simple>
                <ReportID_Complicated>
                    <xsl:variable name="vReport_Id" select="Report_Id"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="../Record[Report_Id = $vReport_Id][generate-id() = generate-id(key('kname4',concat(Report_Id,name4)))]">
                        <xsl:for-each select="../Record[Report_Id = $vReport_Id][name4=current()/name4]">
                            <xsl:variable name="name4" select="name4"/>
                            <xsl:if test="name4='false'">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ReportID_Complicated>
            </Report_Id>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ns:File_Intermediate>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Where is your XSLT?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to start off with the [XSLT identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), which on its own copies all the nodes in the XML as-is

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This means you only need to write templates for the nodes you wish to transform. You want to change `Report_ID` elements into `Report_ID_Complicated` where there is a `Record` with a `name4` of false. This means you just have a template to match such a record

```
<xsl:template match="Recordset/Report_ID[Record/name4 = 'false']">
```

Note the use of the preceding `Recordset` as there are nested `Report_ID` in the XML.

The contents would be similar to the identity template, except you can explicitly create a new node rather than copy the existing one

```
   <Report_ID_Complicated>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </Report_ID_Complicated>
```

For the other template, you could then match the opposite:

```
<xsl:template match="Recordset/Report_ID[not(Record/name4 = 'false')]">
```

Note that it would not be correct to write a second template like this.

```
<xsl:template match="Recordset/Report_ID">
```

This is because XSLT considers this to have the same priority as the previous one, which is an error, so you need the extra xpath condition to distinguish it. Also, note, if you had a template that matched just this...

```
<xsl:template match="Report_ID">
```

This would have a lower priority, which would be acceptable, but in the case of your XML, you have nested `Report_ID` elements which it would also match (Thanks to Lingamurthy CS for pointing this out!)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Recordset/Report_ID[Record/name4 = 'false']">
      <Report_ID_Complicated>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </Report_ID_Complicated>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="Recordset/Report_ID[not(Record/name4 = 'false')]">
      <Report_ID_Simple>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </Report_ID_Simple>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tim C, shouldn't it warn about the "Ambiguous" template for Report_ID as there are two templates matching it. I'm not sure if I'm making sense. I would have used an `xsl:choose` within one template to handle both type of ReportID..

Comment: @LingamurthyCS There is no ambiguity. Both templates match different nodes. The first one those which contain `Record/name4 = 'false'` children, the second one all others. Working with `<xsl:choose>` actually is the inferior way of handling such a situation.

Comment: It works right.. But, with all due respect, the last template that matches `Report_ID` should match `Report_ID`s with `Record/name4 = 'false'` also, right?(I'm just trying to get my concepts right).. BTW, a correction.. there are more descendants named `Report_ID`.. The match should be `Recordset/Report_ID`..

Comment: The last template *would* match them, but only if there was no template that was a *better* match. XSLT does the same thing CSS does - it calculates how specific a match expression is and of all potential matches it uses the most specific one. If there is more than one matching template with the same specificity, the one declared last in the stylesheet is being used (again, CSS does the same thing). That's a core design feature of XSLT, you don't need to re-implement that decision process with `<xsl:choose>`.

Comment: You can read up on template conflict resolution at http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @TimC.. Now, since there are more descendant `Report_ID`s, and the last template will change even those to `Report_ID_Simple`(which isn't expected).. and changing the template to match `Recordset/Report_ID` will create ambiguity.. Now, will it be a must to use only one template?

Comment: @LingamurthyCS Yes, you are absolutely right. I failed to spot there were other `Report_ID` elements in the hierarchy which the second template would then match. I have corrected my answer to handle this now. Thank you for pointing it out!